# Moving files recursively if certain condition is met

Tags: shell, filenames, recursive, mv

I have the following directory tree:

```
records/13/2014.12.16/00/05.mpg
records/13/2014.12.16/00/15.mpg
records/13/2014.12.16/01/05.mpg
records/13/2014.12.16/02/15.mpg
records/15/2014.12.14/05/25.mpg
etc.
```

I need to rename every file which has `*5.mpg` in its name to `*0.mpg`. So for example:

```
mv records/13/2014.12.16/00/05.mpg records/13/2014.12.16/00/00.mpg
mv records/13/2014.12.16/00/15.mpg records/13/2014.12.16/00/10.mpg
mv records/15/2014.12.14/05/25.mpg records/15/2014.12.14/05/20.mpg
etc.
```

I know that I'm gonna have to write a bash script to do that. Unfortunately I'm not good at it, that's why I'm asking you for help.
I guess that it will have to enter each directory (the recursive part) and move every file in that directory if its name contains `*5.mpg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through all `*.5mpg` files and use help of parameter expansion to change filenames:

```
for file in *5.mpg; do mv -- "$file" "${file%5.mpg}"0.mpg; done
```

To do it for different directories set globstar option (`shopt -s globstar` in bash) and additionally take path component with `dirname` command or again using parameter expansion.

Comment: For all directories that should work with globstar: `for file in ./**/*5.mpg; do mv "$file" "${file%5.mpg}"0.mpg; done`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

`find records -type f -iname '*.mpg' | xargs rename 5.mpg 0.mpg`

Since all the files that you want to rename ends with *5.mpg, this `find`+`rename` combo will work just fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I gave a try to write my own script. It seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -iname "*5.mpg" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
   new=${line//5.mpg}
   zero="0.mpg"
   buffer=$new$zero
   new=$buffer
   mv $line $new
   echo "Moving $line"
done
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes around your variables. If you use `-iname` for case insensitive, you can't use `${line//...}`. That won't work properly for files like `./foo5.mpgd/5.mpge5.mpg`. `$'\0'` is misleading as `bash` can't pass NUL characters to a command. That's the same as `-d ''`.